# Why Adding Threads Cannot Bring Further Performance Improvements

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stdatomic

I'm learning multi-threaded programming in C++.
My test procedure is very simple, whose function is to count an atomic variable from 0 to 10000000 (a little higher doesn't matter). I can't understand why after I set the thread number from 8 to 16, the executing time increases a little rather than drops dramatically.

```cpp
std::atomic<int> atomicCounter{0};
void addcount(int threadId) {
    while(atomicCounter.load() < 10000000) {
        atomicCounter.fetch_add(1);
    }
}

void test() {
    const int maxNumThreads = 8;
    // Time::now() is to get the timestamp accurate to ns
    auto s_ts = Time::now();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumThreads; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back([&]() {
            addcount(i);
        });
    }

    // join the threads
    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
    threads.clear();
    auto e_ts = Time::now();
    LOG(INFO) << "Executing time : " << (e_ts - s_ts) / 1000 << " us";
}
```

I have tested several times under 8 threads and 16 threads by changing `maxNumThreads`, and the average executing times are 1.7ms and 1.9ms respectively. My tests run on a machine with an i9-12900k processor which has 16 cores and supports 24 hyper threads in parallel.

My sincere gratitude for any suggestion!

---

I was reminded of the apparent problems in my case so I modified the above code as follows then reran tests. The results are as expectations (executing time drops from 3.0ms to 1.9ms). Thanks for all answers and comments!

```cpp
std::atomic<int> atomicCounter{0};
void addcount(int threadId) {
    while(atomicCounter.load() < 1000) {
        //simulate threads fetch jobs from a queue and execute them once a time
        atomicCounter.fetch_add(1);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++);
    }
}

void test() {
    const int maxNumThreads = 8;
    // get the timestamp accurate to ns
    auto s_ts = Time::now();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumThreads; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back([&]() {
            addcount(i);
        });
    }

    // Join the threads
    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
    threads.clear();
    auto e_ts = Time::now();
    LOG(INFO) << "Executing time : " << (e_ts - s_ts) / 1000 << " us";
}
```

Comment: What kind of clock are you using in `Time::now`? Also in your time calculation you are including threads creation and destruction, not just the work being done. Also I think your `addCount` function is not a good benchmark, because 16 workers incrementing single atomic value actually is not supposed to be any faster than doing same work on a single thread. It;s like asking 16 developers to concurrently develop some simple feature and expecting them to be faster.

Comment: On my machine, an atomic int is about x40 slower than an int (optimized build).  16 threads incrementing the same (atomic) int have to do it sequentially, not in parallel — they are **all** in contention with the single resource.

Comment: your workload (incrementing some shared variable) is inherently non-parallel. Multithreaded programming is not "single threaded + threads", but it requires a complete rethink of how to write programs. Try to see what you get when you comare 1 thread counting till x vs n threads each seperately counting till x/n. That would be the opposite extreme of a maximal parallel workload

Comment: Re, "low contention cost i think," actually, it's just the opposite. Sixteen threads on a sixteen core machine, all doing nothing else but trying to access the same variable. How could there possibly be any more contention than that?

Comment: thanks for your comment. what i said may be questionable, and i want to express that towards using exclusive lock like mutex to solve r/w contentions, atomic is a lower-cost choice. and i mention test environment at the end bacause i think these 16 threads can really execute in parallel in such multi-core environment rather than concurrently in a single-core system, though i ignore that the case i set at the beginning has eliminated their parallel actually.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `atomicCounter.load() < 1000` can be written `atomicCounter < 1000` and `atomicCounter.fetch_add(1)` can be written `atomicCounter++` or `++atomicCounter`.

Comment: Re: `for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++);` -- the compiler can optimize this out, since it has no visible side effects. To introduce a delay, use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Comment: @PeteBecker Some people would consider it good style to use `.load()` and `.fetch_add` explicitly to remind yourself that these are atomic operations (especially if the variable name didn't always have "atomic" in it!).  And to remind readers that you've gone with the default `memory_order_seq_cst`, and make it easier to drop in a different memory order.

Comment: The weird thing with this code is that it doesn't use the return-value of `.fetch_add`, it does a separate load.  I'm curious if that lets it overshoot farther past `1000` across multiple threads, or typically less far.  I'd have done something like `do{}while(atomicCounter.fetch_add(1, relaxed) < 1000);`

Comment: @PeterCordes — some people write overly complex code because they don’t know that it can be written more simply.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Fair enough.  In that sense both things are worth pointing out, both the overloaded conversion and ++, and the fact that `.fetch_add` returns a value.  Using a separate load instead of an RMW return value is often a bug (e.g. if trying to allocate unique IDs across threads dynamically, rather than chopping into ranges), although in this case it's just a different choice.

Comment: Remember that using threads also has overhead - threads need to be created, threads need to be scheduled, threads need to synchronize access to shared state, threads need to be destroyed, etc - that's all extra work that needs to be done and if the work done individually by each thread doesn't outweigh the cost of making that code run in a thread, then you have a net loss, not a win.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot expect sixteen threads to increment the same atomic variable any faster than one thread can do. The reason why not is because, no matter how many threads you have, there is only *one* of the variable, and the threads all must take turns accessing it.

Imagine a classroom full of kids, with a whiteboard, and a wheelbarrow full of marbles. The goal is to count the marbles. So, the teacher draws a box on the whiteboard, writes the number "0" in the box, and instructs the kids:

- Line up,
- Take a marble from the wheelbarrow,
- Increment the number in the box, then
- Go to the back of the line, and repeat until the wheelbarrow is empty.

Adding more kids isn't going to make the process go any faster. What's needed is a better algorithm:

- Every kid gets a bag,
- Line up at the wheelbarrow,
- fill your bag with marbles,
- Take your bag back to your desk, and count how many marbles it contains,
- Line up at the whiteboard,
- Add the number of marbles that you counted at your desk to the number in the box,
- Get another bag full of marbles from the wheelbarrow if it isn't empty and repeat.

The second algorithm is more complicated than the first, but it affords the kids more time to work in *parallel* with each other instead of contending for access to the wheelbarrow and to the whiteboard. Each kid spends most of their time at their own desk, counting their own bag full of marbles--not interacting with each other at all.

Adding more kids in the second scenario *does* get the job done more quickly.*

---

* But there's a diminishing return. Each added kid is worth somewhat less that the previously added kid. You can reach a point where it doesn't make sense to add any more kids. It depends on how quickly they can do their job at the whiteboard and on how much time they spend at their desk counting marbles. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law

Comment: Great analogy.  Also note the more threads/kids you have, the more partial sums you need to collect and reduce, unless you make the reduction algorithm more complicated, too.  (When you and the kid next to you are done, add your numbers together then have the kid on the left go up to the board...)

Comment: And to reflect that atomic RMWs (adding by 1 on a whiteboard with a marker) are more expensive even without contention: locally, a kid can count by 2s and/or make piles of 5 or 10 which they count, except for the leftover few at the end.  (Analogy for loop unrolling and/or SIMD vectors).  They don't need to write down a digit-string representing the total after every marble even on a private whiteboard.

Comment: Even if they just count by 1s in their head, that's fast.  (A compiler keeping the count in a register, instead of load/store at all (store-forwarding latency), let alone the overhead of making it an atomic RMW.)  Another analogy for counting locally with a plain `int` could be making tick-marks in groups of 5 (with the 5th going across a group of 4) to tally locally, although then you have to count groups of 5 or 10 at the end which doesn't directly reflect anything a computer program would do.